# Modify syntax highlighting in vim, remove # as comment

Tags: assembly, vim, syntax

VIM recognises `#` as comments in `.asm` files, however, they're not comments. How can I modify the syntax highlighting to exclude `#` as being recognised a a comment? `;` is correctly recognised as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ASM Pugin

Yes there is an issue with Vim defaults syntax highlighting.

You can try installing asm syntax plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=888

**Install details**

Copy to `$HOME/.vim/syntax` or `$VIM/vimfiles/syntax`

Add the following to your `.vimrc`:

`let asmsyntax='armasm'`
`let filetype_inc='armasm'`